# Detect which dropdown selected and return its value and ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have few drop-down boxes. Is there any way to detect which dropdown was changed using jquery ?

```
<form id="products">
 <select id="Ram">
   <option value="0">4 GB</option>
   <option value="1">8 GB</option>
 </select>

 <select id="Hdd">
   <option value="0">300 GB</option>
   <option value="1">500 GB</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#products').change(function() {
     var value = $(this).val(); //In here I want to detect and return the value.
     alert(value); // Want to return dropdown ID and its selected value
  });
});
```

Comment: why i have a feeling that i have seen that markup before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').not('ids of select tags which you want to exclude seperated by a comma').change(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var value = $(this).val();
     alert('ID ='+id+' Value ='+value);
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to exclude some drop downs from this... How can i do that when use `'select'` ?

Comment: Done using Aditya Parab's improvement answer. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Aspirin is right,

I would just improve his answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#products select').change(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var value = $(this).val();
     alert('ID ='+id+' Value ='+value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i want to do... :)

Comment: @stackminu

If you want to exclude a few select elements then use the specific context to select them...

Foe eg

To the select elements that you want to select, add a class (lets say) "wanted"
and add class (lets say) "notWanted" to the select elements you don't want...

and then use your selector like 

$("#products select .wanted").whatever();

Comment: alright... glad that it helped you...
My previous comment was in the context that you want to filter the elements within #products...

Just ignore it, if it did help you :)